# are there any statistically significant differences between my study population and a sub-group within it?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, population

I have a total population of 31, of these I have a treatment finishing population of 20.

I want to run a test on SPSS to identify if there are any significant differences between the 20 individuals that completed the treatment and the group as a whole.

The variables I am trying to compare are age, weight, height and BMI.

I have run descriptives for both the entire population and the sub group seperatley, I can see there is little difference between the groups but would like to know the statistical significance

Comment: To compare (statistically) a part with a whole is to compare that part with the rest portion of the whole.

Comment: Unless you don't intend your inference to apply outside those 31 subjects, *you don't have 31 in your population*; more likely the 31 is some kind of sample from a population (possibly only a notional one) that you *do* intend to extend your inference to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a sensible question, since the treatment group appears on both sides of the equation. However, a sensible one is to compare the treatments and controls. All of the variables that you are interested in can be treated as continuous, so a good test to compare the whole distribution of the treatment vs. control is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test.

EDIT: let me step back a little bit, and think about this more formally. Suppose you have the population with mean $\mu_0$ with two subgroups, $a$ and $b$ of relative size $f_a$ and $f_b$, where $f_a+f_b=1$, and their means are $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$. Then
$$
\mu_0 = f_a \mu_a + f_b \mu_b,
$$
so the central equality of the hypothesis $H_0: \mu_0 - \mu_a=0$ is equivalent to
$$
\mu_0 - \mu_a = f_a \mu_a + f_b \mu_b - (f_a + f_b) \mu_a = f_a \mu_a + f_b \mu_b - f_a \mu_a - f_b \mu_a = f_b(\mu_b-\mu_a)
$$
and of course for that thing to be zero, $\mu_b-\mu_a$ has to be zero. Hence, testing that the group mean is the same as the overall mean is equivalent to testing that the group mean is different from the mean of the complement.

Things may get a little bit more complicated with finite populations and unknown group sizes, as then uncertainty in the size of the group will also enter the variance expression in the demoninator of the $t$-test. I will not pursue this complication here, however.

And of course things are even more complicated when you want to figure out if other aspects of distributions than the means differ, which is why I was thinking about K-S in the first place.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. There were no controls. It was a weight loss programme, 31 people enrolled, 11 had dropped out by the end of the programme. I wanted to see if there were any differences in the charateristics of the 20 that completed the programme to the whole group. So you think this is not possible?

Comment: I don't think his comment is that it is not possible, but rather that it might not make a ton of sense. The best thing to do would likely be to compare the 20 that COMPLETED to the 11 that DID NOT COMPLETE. This is, after all, likely the question of interest, is it not? To see if the 20 that COMPLETED differ from those who COMPLETED and DID NOT COMPLETE is unusual, since the second group would include the same individuals as the first.

Comment: Ok so I could use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare the 20 that completed to the 11 who did not? Would a paired samples t-test also be suitable in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the group that finished the treatment with the group that didn't (20 vs 11). You want to use a t-test to do that (not a paired t-test since your data isn't paired). That said, the sample size of 11 will determine the statistical power of the test, which will be very low. Only very significant differences in mean will be detected.